# want to give this link to html page in servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

how to give link to Login.html in servlet
This doesnt work

```
             out.print("You are successfully registered");
        out.print("<html>");
        out.print("<body>");
        out.print("<a href='/Login.html'>");
        out.print("</a>");
        out.print("</body>");
        out.print("</html>");
```

Comment: You're printing something before your html document starts. Try moving "You are successfully registered" to within the body.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file `Login.html` is on the root of your webapplication you can use this:

```
out.print(String.format("<a href=\"%s/Login.html\">", req.getContextPath()));
```

Where `req` is of type `HttpServletRequest`. So if your web application is mapped to context `mywebapp` the link will be: `/mywebapp/Login.html`.

If your web app is mapped to the root context the link will be `/Login.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect. You just missed the text to be written between two `<a>` and `</a>`. Your link will not be visible without that text. Try this :-

```
out.print("<a href='LoginTest.html'>Link</a>");
```

Mark the problem solved if it solves your problem.